# Retrieving from database returns null instead of values added

Tags: c#, dataset

```
SqlConnection cone = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnx);

void viewdata() {
    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select movie_name,movie_date,movie_desc from movies", cone);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

My table has 4 rows so I notice it returns 5 empty DataGrid rows, even though I made sure the database was filled with data

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns = true`?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET (web), then you need to have a `dataGridView1.DataBind();` **after** your `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`, too!

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns = true doesn't change anything here https://i.imgur.com/gpFxAe7.png

Comment: marc_s dataGridView1.DataBind(); is not needed as i'm using windows forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling it manually worked and got variables instead of Nulls

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT nom_cinema,addresse,heur_ouverture,heur_fermeture FROM [dbo].[cinema]", con);

                SqlDataReader cv = cmd.ExecuteReader();



                while (cv.Read())
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cv.GetValue(0).ToString(), cv.GetValue(1).ToString(), cv.GetValue(2).ToString(), cv.GetValue(3).ToString());

                }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void viewdata() {
    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select movie_name as movie,movie_date as date,movie_desc as desc from movies", cone);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

and set `AutoGenerateColumns` property of grid to `true`

Comment: can you scroll the horizontal scroll bar to the right? and make sure AutoGenerateColumns property of grid to true?